# When loading CSS with webpack, I can write CSS for tags, but not for classes or ids

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, webpack

I have loaded CSS using webpack and can style HTML tags, but cannot style using classes or ids. I'm wondering if it has to do with my order of dependencies, or the way I am loading the CSS.

For example, this works:

```
span {
    background-color: teal;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* We'll override this later */
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
.bar {
    background-color: teal;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* We'll override this later */
}
```

This is my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = { 
  entry: './src/index.js', 
  output: { 
    path: path.resolve('dist'), 
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  }, 

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }, 
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

This is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js file.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import styles from './style.css';

var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
```

Comment: This is a great first question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you have enabled  [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in your webpack configuration. During a build, the classes will be replaced with generated ones (local classes). In order to disable css modules for your configuration simply change the property to `modules: false`, as such:

```
use: [
  { loader: 'style-loader'},
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: false
    }
  },
]
```

Or, if you want to keep css modules on and fix the problem you must either:

1) use generated classes in your HTML

2) change your selectors to global as:

```
:global{
    .bar {
        background-color: teal;
        display: inline-block; 
        width: 20px;
        height: 75px;   /* We'll override this later */
    }
}
```